# Connecting thru Cloud Interconnect(GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am very new to GCP, my company uses internal interconnect devices for direct peering from DC to GCP. Question is, whenever i create a project and spawn a VM, do i still need to create a network inside the project?

Comment: What do you mean by create a network inside the project? VPC Network? Subenet? And which project? Your new project, or the interconnect host project? Can you describe more precisely your question? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can spin up a VM only if you have a VPC network in place already.